# How to get Apache to use upgraded PHP

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I need to upgrade to a higher version of php. My current version is 5.1.6.

So I am trying to upgrade php to version 5.3.26.

php installed just fine in /usr/local.

But at least according to wordpress, apache is still seeing the older version of php.

The .bashrc and .bash_profile have been modified for root to point to /usr/local/bin first (where the newer version of php is installed).

What else do I need to do?

Comment: The PHP 5.1.6 part makes me think that this is you trying to get PHP 5.3.x on a RHEL5 or CentOS 5 machine. If that's the case, you should realize there's already a binary package for that (which includes its own apache configuration) called `php53`. You'll have to uninstall the regular `php` package, since there are obviously going to be conflicting files between the two.

Comment: The default version is lower than 5.3.x, and I currently can't get this off RH due to subscription problems.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `php53` that CentOS provides? Even though it's RHEL the RPM should still work for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary slightly based on the distribution you're using. In all cases, you need to change what's being loaded by Apache in the `httpd.conf` file.

Debian based systems (Ubuntu, etc) use a structure of include files which are included into `httpd.conf`, rather than editing it directly. All of the module include directives are stored in `/etc/apache2/mods-available` as `.conf` and `.load` and then if they're enabled, a symlink is created in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

Following the Debian convention, the best way to changeover to the new PHP would be to disable the current PHP module using `a2dismod`.

```
a2dismod php5
```

Then copy the `php5.conf` and `php5.load` files in `/etc/apache2/mods-available` to a new name such as `php53.load` and change the path to your new `.so` file so that you can later switch back to 5.1.6 easily if necessary.

Finally just enable the new module with `a2enmod`.

```
a2enmod php53
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to rebuild apache from source, including apr, apr-util, and pcre. Then I rebuilt php with make distclean; ./configure --with-apxs2 --with-curl; and then make && make install.